# Facebook API Specification

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am beginner in PHP and i was trying to integrate facebook social plug-ins with my website.I have gone through the Runkeeper website(http:runkeeper.com) for the facebook share plugin, i don't know how the friends of me in facebook(he is also the member of runkeeper.com) activity displays in my runkeeper page "http://runkeeper.com/user/Testingwebdeveloper/streetTeam page". i don't even shared anything from runkeeper website in the facebook share. But whenever someone do some activities in the runkeeper website and if he is friend of me in facebook , then his activities will be displayed in my webpage of runkeeper. This is how the Tracking of Activity goes on with the help of some Facebook API, i have seen this website is built using Android , so is there anyway and some one please give me some ideas to do this same kind of feature in my website using PHP and facebook API.

I have gone through the social plugin in the facebook, but it was not quite to make it as per the runkeeper.com. So please guide me or provide  anyother referral website to learn more about this feature.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

The guy is either a genius or he is simply using the [Facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) and the [Activity Feeds](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/) plugins!

I suggest you have a look at the full list of Facebook [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/).

Just three notes:

1. Facebook will NOT share your "*Facebook identity*" with any website unless:

   - **YOU** connect to that site
   - **THAT SITE** becoms a Facebook partner and use [Instant Personalization](http://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/).
2. It's **Facebook** not *face-book* :-)
3. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Ok mate.Thanks for your suggestion.i will check with Facepile and other things that you have mentioned